# Confusion with first condition of Chomsky Normal Form

Tags: context-free, terminology, formal-grammars

I had a very quick question when it comes to CFG (more specifically the attributes of CNF). I've been browsing over some examples and I've come across a few that confuse me. One such example is this:

$$\begin{align}S&\to XA|BB\\
B&\to b|SB\\
X&\to b\\
A&\to a\\
\end{align}$$

It is stated that this is indeed in CNF, but my confusion lies in the fact that under most rules it is stated that if the starting state $S$ exists in some RHS (in this case $B\to b|SB$) we must create a rule that states $S'\to S$.

Since that doesn't exist in this example, why is this considered to be in CNF? I also understand the rules of CNF, I also see that this example technically satisfies all those rules, so I am wondering if that is the reason?

***Rules:***
$$\begin{align}A&\to a\\
A&\to BC\\
\end{align}$$

Thank you for the help in advance!

Here is the link to the question for reference ( it deals with CFG TO GNF) 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/converting-context-free-grammar-greibach-normal-form/

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, your context-free grammar is in Chomsky Normal Form.

A grammar is in CNF whenever its rules are of one of two types, either $A\to BC$ or $A\to a$, where $A,B,C$ are nonterminals, and $a$ is a terminal symbol.

This means that every context-free grammar is equivalent to a cf grammar in CNF, up to the empty word. 
This means that by conversion into CNF one might loose the empty word. Nobody cares. Wikipedia refers to [Hopcroft and Ullman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form) as the source for CNF, and here is what H&U write:

> **Theorem 4.5** (*Chomsky normal form, or CNF*)
>   Any context-free language without $\epsilon$ is generated by a
>   grammar in which all productions are of the form 
>   $A\to BC$ or $A\to a$. Here, $A$, $B$, and $C$, are variables and $a$ is a terminal.

Except that some people with a wretched feeling for precision did not like this idea. They came up with a complicated formulation, just to capture the empty string. Probably something like "If the language contains $\epsilon$ then we allow the production $S\to \epsilon$, where $S$ is the axiom, and $S$ does not occur on the right-hand side of productions."

Well, your example grammar does not generate $\epsilon$ anyhow, so I would not bother. Chomsky didn't, Hopcroft and Ullman didn't. However, this is not legal advise. So, if someone is checking your exams, then I would consult that person.

Fun fact, Chomsky called "his" normal form "regular grammars"(!) and added a more restrictive condition: no two rules $A\to \alpha$ and $A\to \beta$ could share a common symbol in their right-hand sides $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (unless of course $\alpha =\beta$). (Definition 8, page 149, in the 1959 Chomsky paper linked at wikipedia).