# Empty string in language with grammar in Chomsky normal form

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

In their [book](https://www.amazon.in/Introduction-Automata-Theory-Languages-Computation-ebook/dp/B075GHWDHT), Ullman et al says:

> Every nonempty CFL without $\epsilon$ has a grammar $G$ in which all productions are in one of two simple forms, either:
>
> 1. $A\rightarrow BC$, where $A,B$ and $C$, are each variables, or
> 2. $A\rightarrow a$, where $A$ is a variable and $a$ is a terminal
>
> Further $G$ has no useless symbols. Such a grammar is said to be in Chomsky Normal Form or CNF.

whereas wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form):

> In formal language theory, a context-free grammar $G$ is said to be in Chomsky normal form if all of its production rules are of the form:
>   $A → BC$,   or
>   $A → a$,   or
>   $S → ε$,
>   where $A$, $B$, and $C$ are nonterminal symbols, $a$ is a terminal symbol (a symbol that represents a constant value), $S$ is the start symbol, and $ε$ denotes the empty string. Also, neither $B$ nor $C$ may be the start symbol, and the third production rule can only appear if $ε$ is in $L(G)$.

Also [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/converting-context-free-grammar-chomsky-normal-form/) site says:

> Any Context free Grammar that do not have $ε$ in it’s language has an equivalent CNF.

So, whats correct?

1. Can we have $S\rightarrow \epsilon$ in CNF or not? (According to Ullman, no, according to wikipedia, yes) If yes, can other non terminals have $\epsilon$ production? (According to all sources, no)
2. Can $L(G)$ contain $\epsilon$? (According to Ullman and third reference, no, according to wikipedia, yes)

Am I missing something? and incorrectly trying to relate these sources out of some context?

Comment: It is a matter of taste. Either you include $\epsilon$ and allow a special $S\to\epsilon$ rule (as Wikipedia does), or do not care about $\epsilon$ in the language and have a clean definition (following Hopcroft&Ullman). I side with Hopcroft, and Chomsky himself. You may read my [rant](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/111124/4287) on this matter.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for those sources to decide to allow / disallow $\epsilon$ for it to have equivalent Chomsky Normal Form? Is there any effect of allowing / disallowing  $\epsilon$ on any other related concept?

Comment: The reason is "elegance", does it look right for you. Does the definition look good, does it match your intuition about what it should formalize. Note how Wikipedia is cheating: they claim to adhere to Hopcroft and Ullman, with reference and fancy pagenumbers, and then cite an alternative definition.

Comment: In several cases including/excluding $\epsilon$ might be important. One that comes to mind is in allowing $\epsilon$ as image for string homomorphisms in the theory of [Abstract Families of Languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_family_of_languages).